# Codeigniter set default form value from Controller to View

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, crud

I just got tired to find out, why the below warning message is generated with my Codeigniter Project.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Creating default object from empty value

Filename: controllers/person.php

Line Number: 268
```

In My person Controller,

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // load library
        $this->load->library(array('table','form_validation'));

        // load helper
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->config('array_constant', TRUE);

        // load model
        $this->load->model('Person_model','',TRUE);
    }
// set empty default form field values
    function _set_fields()
    {
        Line No: 268 $this->form_data->id = '';
        $this->form_data->name = '';
        $this->form_data->gender = '';
        $this->form_data->dob = '';
        $this->form_data->district = '';
        $this->form_data->education = '';
        $this->form_data->occupation = '';
        $this->form_data->annual_income = '';
        $this->form_data->company_name = '';
        $this->form_data->description = '';
    }
```

In My View file,

```
<table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="30%">ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" disabled="disable" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('id'); ?>"/></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo set_value('id',$this->form_data->id); ?>"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" class="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name',$this->form_data->name); ?>"/>
<?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Any idea or suggestions to suppress the  above warning!

```
echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->form_data);
        echo "</pre>";

object(stdClass)#21 (10) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["gender"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["dob"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["district"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["education"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["occupation"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["annual_income"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["company_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: can you try **var_dump($this->form_data);** please and report here the dump?

Comment: I do notice you aren't setting the 2nd argument for `set_value('id');` not sure if that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: Which line is line #268 in person.php?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.Hi Badaboooooom, I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi cryptic, Yes the line 268 in person.php

Comment: @Yadheendran, I was asking what line of code in your post is line 268 in person.php?

Comment: Thanks. The line no 268 is first line of _set_fields() function.

Comment: @Yadheendran, please try my below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This notice is generated in PHP 5.4 and up. It's not an error, it's a notice - intended to help you debug your application and raise awareness of possible problems.

When you call `_set_fields` initially, `$this->form_data` is `NULL`, then you attempt to treat a NULL like an object with this line:

```
$this->form_data->id = '';
```

`NULL` can't have properties like "id", so the notice is telling you that PHP assumed you wanted an object, so it made one automatically for you.

There are a lot of ways to solve this that entail some restructuring of your code, but a simple solution to silence the notice:

```
$this->form_data = new stdClass;
$this->form_data->id = '';
// etc.
```

A better solution is to use a class for your object, very simple example:

```
$this->form_data = new MY_Form_Data_Object();

class MY_Form_Data_Object { // use a better name that describes what this is
    public $name = '';
    public $gender = '';
    public $dob = '';
    // etc.
    // add some helpful methods here when needed, like validation
    // maybe a constructor to initialize some values
}
```

Comment: Wow. Its great... I used your simple solution to suppress the warning! Again thanks for your great suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, except that i was not able to change all my code.

To let CI suppress the warning i set the ENVIRONMENT to production in the index.php:

```
//define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Basically CI sets the error reporting

```
error_reporting(0);
```